# How do I unlock an old iPad with Activation Lock without knowing the Apple ID password?

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-id, password, activation-lock

I want to start using my old iPad again. I forgot my old Apple ID and the iPad is stuck on the activation lock screen after resetting it to factory settings. I used a different Apple ID for my iPad and iPhone, so I don't remember the password. I don't remember the answers to the security questions. I cannot change the password for this account. The iPad is running iOS 9.

I have looked into some shady internet tips recommending an app to unlock it, but the app doesn't work when activation lock is on.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has the following information on their [page for Activation Lock for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365):

> If you forget your Apple ID or password Your Apple ID is the account
>   that you use to sign in to all Apple services. Usually, your Apple ID
>   is your email address. If you forget your Apple ID, [we can help you
>   find it](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201354).
>
> If you forget your password, you can [reset it from your device or your
>   Apple ID account page](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201487).
>
> **If you can't find your Apple ID or reset your password, you'll lose
>   access to your account and might be unable to use or reactivate your
>   device.** To help prevent this, [visit your Apple ID account page](http://your%20Apple%20ID%20account%20page)
>   periodically to review and update your account information.

Unfortunately, you are probably out of luck.

Since your iPad was unused and running iOS 9, it's probably pretty old and may not be worth any money in [Apple's Trade-in Program](https://www.apple.com/shop/trade-in) as a non-functioning device, but can be recycled free of charge. ([Nation-specific recycling programs can be found here](https://www.apple.com/recycling/nationalservices/)). Other people or companies may be willing to purchase non-functioning devices for parts.